# How to map hive warehouse path in hive-site.xml?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I'm new to ubuntu, and I'm trying to install hive 3.0.0 on my system. 
I'm following a tutorial on internet and I came across this command.

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir -p /user/hive/warehouse
hdfs dfs -mkdir /tmp
```

This command are used to store metadata. But I can't find those in filesystem.

**So my question is that, what is the meaning of this commands? 
And how to map that metadata on hive-site.xml?**

Following is the hive-site.xml from my tutorial.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="confguration.xsl"?><!--
Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
contri utor license agreements. See the NOTICE fle distributed with
this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
The ASF licenses this fle to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
(the "License"); you may not use this fle except in compliance with
the License. You may o tain a copy of the License at
http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
Unless required y applicable law or agreed to in writing, software-->




<confguration>
<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
<value>jdbc:mysql://localhost/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
<description>
JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore.
To use SSL to encrypt/authenticate the connection, provide database-specifc SSL fag in
the connection URL.
For example, jdbc:postgresql://myhost/d ?ssl=true for postgres database.
</description>
</property>
<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>

<value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
<description>Driver class name for a JDBC metastore</description>
</property>
<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
<value>hiveuser</value>
<description>Username to use against metastore database</description>
</property>

<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
<value>password@123</value>
<description>password to use against metastore database</description>
</property>
<property>
<name>datanucleus.autoCreateSchema</name>
<value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>datanucleus.fxedDatastore</name>


<value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>datanucleus.autoCreateTables</name>
<value>True</value>
</property>
</confguration>
```

**I'm using mysql to store metadata. Please explain necessary changes, if any.

THANKS IN ADVANCE!!!
**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This command are used to store metadata

Not quite. That's the Hive Warehouse directory on HDFS. This is where the raw data exists, not the metadata - that is entirely in Mysql.

HDFS is configured by the core-site.xml of the Hadoop client libraries required by Hive, not the hive-site.xml file

> But I can't find those in filesystem.

Probably because those are HDFS paths, not places on your local filesystem

> what is the meaning of this commands?

To create the default warehouse and temp scratch directories needed to store data to be used by Hive processes

Comment: what changes are required in hadoop configuration (like hdfs-site.xml,yarn-site.xml etc) for mysql mapping apart from hive configurations?@cricket_007

Comment: None of those files care about Mysql, only Hive